# Schrodinger equation violates mathematics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers

By the Hamiltonian formalism of quantum mechanics, given a quantum system in a state $\Psi$ in a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, the state will instantaneously evolve in time according to
$$\dot{\Psi}=\frac{i}{\hbar}H\Psi.\tag{1}$$
Since $\Psi^*$ is also an element of the Hilbert space, it evolves in time in accordance with (1): just apply the Hamiltonian:
$$\dot{\Psi^*}=\frac{i}{\hbar}H\Psi^*.\tag{2}$$
Now consider the simple case of a free hamiltonian in one dimension:
$$\mathcal H=L^2(\mathbb{R}),~~~~H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}.$$
By the linearity of the derivative, *complex conjugation commutes with differentiation*:
$$\frac{\partial^2(\Psi^*)}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2(\Re\Psi)}{\partial x^2}-i\frac{\partial^2(\Im\Psi)}{\partial x^2}=\left(\frac{\partial^2(\Re\Psi)}{\partial x^2}+i\frac{\partial^2(\Im\Psi)}{\partial x^2}\right)^*=\left(\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2}\right)^*$$
$$\dot{\Psi^*}=\dot{\Re\Psi}-i\dot{\Im\Psi}=(\dot{\Re\Psi}+i\dot{\Im\Psi})^*=\dot{\Psi}^*.$$
And therefore,
$$\dot{\Psi^*}=\frac{i}{\hbar}\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2(\Psi^*)}{\partial x^2}\right)= \left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\left(\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2}\right)\right)^*$$
$$~~~~=-\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2}\right)\right)^*=-\dot{\Psi}^*=-\dot{\Psi^*}~~\Rightarrow\Leftarrow.$$

So here is my question: **Are derivatives linear, or is the Schrodinger equation mathematically consistent?** (pick one of two)

Comment: Your problem is with equation (2).  When you applied $*$ to equation (1), you forgot to conjugate the $i$, which would convert it to $-i$.

Comment: I never applied * to equation (1). I just applied the hamiltonian to $\Psi^*$ to figure out how it evolved in time. (2) is a separate equation.

Comment: Why should $\psi^*$ satisfy the Schrodinger equation?

Comment: because it is a quantum state.

Comment: The quantum state of what?

Comment: what's your favorite quantum dynamical system?

Comment: You are saying that *any arbitrarily chosen quantum system* has the quantum state $\psi^*$?  So all quantum systems are identical????????????

Comment: Yes to the first question, and no to the second. I never told you what $\psi$ was.

Comment: The second follows from the first.  I don't think there's much point in continuing this bizarre discussion.

Comment: I don't see that. How so? Perhaps if you were clearer, I would get what you're getting at. Anyways, sure, if we can't understand each other, then there's no point in continuing the discussion.

Comment: Instead of downvoting, can people enlighten me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31544/discussion-between-willo-and-dave).

Comment: The following could be helpful in clearing the confusion: What you call $\Psi$ is not an element of a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, but a function $\Psi:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathcal H$ assigning a Hilbert space state to every instant of time $t$. While a quantum system can be in ANY quantum state at a given point in time, the TIME EVOLUTION of this quantum state depends on the Hamiltonian $H$. The problem with your equation (2) is that the time evolution of $\Psi$ is consistent with $H$, but the evolution of $\Psi^*$ is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is your Eq 1 and 2 that are mathematically inconsistent -- just take complex conjugate on both sides of Eq 1 and you will see. I think you confused a state being an element of the Hilbert space and a state satisfying the schrodinger equation. I can write down plenty of elements of the Hilbert space that does not satisfy the Schrodinger equation, for example, a plane wave state does not satisfy the Schrodinger equation of a hydrogen atom. Nobody said $\Psi$ and $\Psi^*$ should satisfy the same Schrodinger equation of the same Hamiltonian - if you impose mathematical consistency you see their corresponding Hamiltonians are opposite to each other.